# Undo "Default Home Sceen" as my default home screen

Tags: android

In my app I am trying to override the default home screen. For that purpose, I have created an activity of category "HOME". When the app launches, it is prompting the user to select the App(Showing my app and default Launcher) to complete the action. If I select "Launcher" ( Default Home screen), then there is no way to choose my app as default home screen.

Can somebody tell me if there a way to undo the "Default Home Screen" as my default launcher for Home activity?

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> [Launcher App] -> Defaults

Comment: He is asking to do this pragmatically, not by hand.

Answer (score 1):

[`clearPackagePreferredActivities()` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29) should allow you to do this programmatically, for your own app.

Comment: The problem is Android's default home screen is set as default App for HomeActivity. I want to undo the same, so that when I launch my app, it should prompt the user to choose the app for home screen.

Comment: @user2107151: That is not possible. It also should not be necessary, as on most devices, simply installing your app should bring up the chooser again on the next HOME button press. For those devices that have messed this up somehow, users can go in and follow the steps outlined by Rajesh in his comment to remove the default status from apps, forcing a chooser to appear again.

Comment: @user2107151 **"An application can only clear its own package(s)"** So I don't think you can do this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare and WajeEh :)